# Showing edit form for specific element with condition instead of for all

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have list of items , and for each list of item I have edit form.

```
         <div *ngFor="let task of fridayEvents;let i = index" class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="event-holder">
          <div class="event--image_background" [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + task?.imageSource + ')'"></div>

          <div *ngIf="!editmode">
            <span> {{ task?.eventName }} </span>
            <span> {{ task?.eventAddress }} </span>
            <span> {{ task?.startHour}} </span>
            <span> {{ task?.endHour}} </span>
            <span> {{ task?.eventDescription }}</span>
          </div>

          <div *ngIf="editmode" class="edit--form">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input #editEventName matInput type="text" name="edit_eventName" value="{{ task?.eventName }}">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field>
              <input #editEventAddress matInput type="text" name="edit_eventAddress" value="{{ task?.eventAddress }}">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field>
              <input #editEventStartHour matInput type="number" value="{{ task?.startHour }}">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field>
              <input #editEventEndHour matInput type="number" value="{{ task?.endHour }}">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field>
              <textarea #editEventDescription matInput value="{{ task?.eventDescription }}" name="" rows="10"></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>

            <button type="button" (click)="submitEdit($event, i , editEventName , editEventAddress, editEventStartHour, editEventEndHour, editEventDescription)">Save</button>
          </div>

          <button type="button" (click)="turnOnEditMode($event, i)">Edit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

so let's say my "fridayEvents" is list of 10 objects. so I have 10 columns , when click on the `Edit` button , setting `editmode = false` but the editform becomes active for all the objects instead for the specific one only. Is there a way turning `editmode` only for the specific element or rather than , I can create 1 edit form place it on the end of `</body>` tag and then taking the values within fridayEvents.object.id for the `values` of inputs and etc... ?

Comment: You need one flag per task (if you want multiple edited items), or an editedTask field (if you only want one task to be edited at a time).

Comment: I'd like one task to be edited at a time , since every task has its own edit form. I'm working with firebase , so when editing , taking the object id and then .update() it based on the event id :)

Comment: So, instead of a boolean editedMode, use a Task editedTask: `*ngIf="task === editedTask"`

Comment: I've managed to do it like ... *ngIf="task.editmode" , then on the click function fridayevents[index].editmode = true;

Comment: Then you'll have several edited tasks at once by clicking on several tasks... And BTW, why use `fridayevents[index]` insted of just `task`

Comment: because I'm enabling the edit formm with separated function in my component's .ts , but yeah , (click)="task.editmode = true;" works as well :)